# In JBehave, how do I pass an array as a parameter from a story file to a step file?

Tags: java, bdd, jbehave

I've been reading the JBehave docs and I'm not finding anything that speaks to this specific use case. The closest I found was [this](http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/parametrised-scenarios.html) on parameterised scenarios, but it's not quite what I'm looking for. I don't need to run the same logic many times with different parameters, I need to run the step logic once with a set of parameters. Specifically, I need to pass combinations of the numbers 1-4. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean something like [Tabular Parameters](http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/tabular-parameters.html)?

You could use it like this:

```
Given the numbers: 
|combinations|
|1234|
|4321|
|1324|
When ...
```

and then:

```
@Given("the numbers: $numbersTable")
public void theNumbers(ExamplesTable numbersTable) {

    List numbers = new ArrayList();
    for (Map<String,String> row : numbersTable.getRows()) {
        String combination = row.get("combinations");
        numbers.add(combination);
    }
}
```

I just rewrote the jBehave example so it could fit your needs. You can pass any count of combinations into the tables inside the given,when,then steps and transform it to an array or in my example into a list.